# Detecting non-empty UI labels

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, uilabel

I have an iOS app in which I am trying to programmatically change the background colour of some UI labels, specifically those which are in a given array and have a non-empty string. My logic is as follows:

```
for (UILabel* label in labels) {
        if([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            if ([labelsToColor containsObject:label] && label.text.length) {
                label.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
            }
        }
}
```

However I'm finding that even labels which have an empty string are being colored (although they are still in the `labelsToColor` array). Can anyone advise?

Comment: How did you add lables?  what label's superview?

Comment: can you print this `labelsToColor`

Comment: for (UILabel* label in labels)  here can you describe your labels array.